# Backup using linked server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linked-server

i am working  on project in which we need to take backup of our database(schedule backup at Every 5 min SQL SERVER 2012) to remote server(SQL SERVER 2012) . now if server crashed for some reason then our website should automatically be connected with other server. can we use linked server for that of something else we can do

Comment: I wouldn't do this in code.. I would set this up at the DB server / cluster level.

Comment: my website is online exam so during exam if SQL server crashed than also exam should not be interrupted. and i`m new in Asp.net so can you tell me how to achieve this

Comment: This is exactly what an SQL cluster is for, if one node goes down, another node (or more) exists and without any downtime is automatically in use, and this is transparent to the applications which connect to the SQL server. Use the right tools for the job.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be about administrative issues, not programming.

Comment: i am student and this is my collage project. and i amd my team mate is programer,Designer,DBA,tester whatever... so this is not off-topic

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to follow the standard solution for simple redundancy scenarios which is [database mirroring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934127%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). [Automatic failover](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189590%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) works with having a **witness** machine which handles the database communication and in case a database server fails, the traffic is redirected to its mirror automatically.

However, note that this architecture leaves you with **a single point of failure, the witness**. If the witness fails, you have to use redundancy strategy for it. The advantage is that this new recovery process, will not include the database recovery process itself.

Hope I helped!